# UFT execution cannot export screen recorder

Tags: hp-uft, alm, uft14, uft-api

In some specific machines, I am executing tests with UFT.

After execution it gives this error:

```
the following report types could not be exported:screen recorder
```

I configured it the same way as my local computer. In my PC works fine but in the others error appears.

I already investigate and some searches bring me to this log/error (temp). I dont really know if its related.

```
[Err] 9 ExporterAutomation.ExportPane: Pane export failed. Pane: MoviePlayerPane 
Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
...\AppData\Local\Temp\TD_80\tls-ws2008-01\f51d31c1\Test\Res3\Report\MSR.fbr
```

How can I debug this or configure this correctly?

I do not want to store a movie. Only application screenshots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that the screen recorder is for video so its not related directly with screenshots.
So I change GUI execution properties to "save images always" and "save movie for errors" and export error is gone.

[image]